# K8s Forbidden Attempt to Grant Extra Privileges

Tags: rest, kubernetes, rbac

Not being able to create a ClusterRole using K8s REST APIs. I receive "forbidden: attempt to grant extra privileges" error. Even though can create same ClusterRole using 'kubectl apply'. Using same user. Running in GCP. Version: '1.11.6-gke.3'.

Here are my steps:

### 1. IAM Config

IAM User: berlioz-robot@xxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com
Role: Kubernetes Engine Admin

### 2. Make the user admin

apply using kubectl:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: berlioz:robot-cluster-admin-binding
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
subjects:
- apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: User
  name: berlioz-robot@xxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

### 3. Generate Login Token

Header:

```
{
  "alg": "RS256",
  "typ": "JWT",
  "kid": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}
```

Payload:

```
{
  "iss": "berlioz-robot@xxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "sub": "berlioz-robot@xxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "aud": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token",
  "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform",
  "iat": 1548743213,
  "exp": 1548746813
}
```

### 4. Login

```
URL: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token
Method: POST
Body: {
    'grant_type': 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer',
    'assertion': here-goes-the-signed-token
}
```

Result:

```
{
    "access_token": "ya29.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "expires_in": 3600,
    "token_type": "Bearer"
}
```

### 5. Create new ClusterRole with REST APIs

```
URL: https://CLUSTER-IP-ADDRESS/apis/rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1/clusterroles
Method: POST
Headers: {
    Authorization: "Bearer ya29.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    Content-Type: "application/json"
}
Body: {
    "metadata": {
      "name": "berlioz:controller-cluster-role"
    },
    "rules": [
      {
        "verbs": [
          "get",
          "list",
          "watch"
        ],
        "apiGroups": [
          ""
        ],
        "resources": [
          "nodes"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "kind": "ClusterRole",
    "apiVersion": "rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1"
}
```

RESULT:

```
{
    "kind": "Status",
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "metadata": {},
    "status": "Failure",
    "message": "clusterroles.rbac.authorization.k8s.io \"berlioz:controller-cluster-role-test\" is forbidden: attempt to grant extra privileges: [{[get] [] [nodes] [] []} {[list] [] [nodes] [] []} {[watch] [] [nodes] [] []}] user=&{110887992956644566571  [system:authenticated] map[user-assertion.cloud.google.com:[xxxxx]]} ownerrules=[{[create] [authorization.k8s.io] [selfsubjectaccessreviews selfsubjectrulesreviews] [] []} {[get] [] [] [] [/api /api/* /apis /apis/* /healthz /openapi /openapi/* /swagger-2.0.0.pb-v1 /swagger.json /swaggerapi /swaggerapi/* /version /version/]}] ruleResolutionErrors=[]",
    "reason": "Forbidden",
    "details": {
        "name": "berlioz:controller-cluster-role-test",
        "group": "rbac.authorization.k8s.io",
        "kind": "clusterroles"
    },
    "code": 403
}
```

Interestingly, if I set list of rules empty, things go through. As mentioned above, same cluster role is getting created using kubectl successfully.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Google cloud RBAC documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/role-based-access-control):

> In GKE, Cloud IAM and Kubernetes RBAC are integrated to authorize users to perform actions if they have sufficient permissions according to either tool. This is an important part of bootstrapping a GKE cluster, since **by default GCP users do not have any Kubernetes RBAC RoleBindings**.
>
> Once users or GCP service accounts are authenticated, they must also be authorized to perform any action on a GKE cluster.
>
> In GKE clusters using GKE v1.11.x and older, there is a limitation that Cloud IAM cannot grant the ability to create a Kubernetes [RBAC Role or ClusterRole](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/role-based-access-control#role). However, the [Kubernetes Engine Admin Cloud IAM role](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/iam#kubernetes-engine-roles) does grant users with the ability to create a Kubernetes RBAC [RoleBinding or ClusterRoleBinding](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/role-based-access-control#rolebinding) for any user, including themselves, which can be used to bind GCP users to [predefined RBAC Roles](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#user-facing-roles).
>
> In particular, the `cluster-admin` predefined RBAC role grants users full permissions in the cluster. Therefore, to bootstrap a user to allow them to create RBAC Roles and ClusterRoles, issue the following command, replacing [USER_ACCOUNT] with the target user's GCP login email address.

```
kubectl create clusterrolebinding cluster-admin-binding \
  --clusterrole cluster-admin \
  --user [USER_ACCOUNT]
```

> **Note**: The [USER_ACCOUNT] is case sensitive. To avoid errors, enter the target user's email address in lowercase.

Alternatively you can use the following yaml:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: cluster-admin-binding
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
subjects:
- apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: User
  name: username@google-account-domain.com
```

After creating such ClusterRoleBinding you'll be able to create ClusterRole.